# Creating a class and storing information in Arrays

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, class, uiscrollview

Trying to create an app where I can categorize a book by feelings. I can pick categories like happiness, fear, sadness, etc and then the specific text and chapter shows up where I can scroll through each one horizontally. I'm at the point where all I need to do is find an easier way to grab the chapter and text from a class and create a function where I can individually call out the chapter and class in my `UIScrollView`.

I have a model for `BookBank` and a model for `HappyText`.
The happy text model is where I store everything just on happiness.
I need to find a way to individually call out the text and chapter so I can grab that information and feature it on `UIScrollView`.

```
class BookBank {

    let chapter : String
    let verse : String

    init(chapter: String, verse: String) {
        self.chapter = chapter
        self.verse = verse
    }  
}

class HappyText {

    var list = [BookBank]()

    init() {

        list.append(BookBank(chapter: "Chapter 1", text: "And he rejoiced in happiness."))
        list.append(BookBank(chapter: "Chapter 1", text: "The business was doing well and his health was improving."))
        list.append(BookBank(chapter: "Chapter 2", text: "John walked down to the harbor to greet his wife and had the biggest smile on his face"))

    }   
}

class FeatureViewVC: UIViewController {

    var featureArray = [String]()
    let book = HappyText()
    var bookChapter = [String]()
    var bookText = [String]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {    
        super.viewDidLoad()

        if feelingLabel.text == "Happiness" {
            featureArray = []
        } else if feelingLabel.text == "Fear" {
            featureArray = []
        }
    }

    func loadText() {
        var bookChapter = [book.list(chapter)]
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you want to use UITableView?

Comment: you mean: featureArray = Array(list)? .//the list is HappyText.list

Comment: you could also make in your controller: 'var happyText:HappyText = HappyText()' and than if you want a chapter: 'happyText.list[index].chapter' or as you have in your loadText(): 'book.list[index].chapter'

Comment: @M.Wojcik I am getting this error saying  Cannot convert value of type '(Any) -> Int' to expected argument type '(UnboundedRange_) -> ()'

Comment: I am using this:     func loadText() {
       bookChapter = book.list[index].chapter
       bookText = book.list[index].text
        }

Comment: Instead of index you need to put an Int number. Check my answer

Answer (score 0):

I'll give you an example of code here, according to my comments.

First of all, in your BookBank model you have 2 parameters: `chapter` and `verse`. But when you make a list inside HappyText model, when initializing BookBank you give `text` instead of `verse`. I also can't see any outlet collection to feelingLabel label, but I suppose you just didn't add it in the question example.

Anyway, working example of `loadText()` method:

```
func loadText() {
        //instead of index you need to put an Int number, like here:
        var bookChapter = [book.list[1].chapter]
        var bookVerse = [book.list[1].verse]

        print("Chapter: \(bookChapter), verse: \(bookVerse)")
    }
```

Now calling `loadText()` would print you:

```
Chapter: ["Chapter 1"], verse: ["The business was doing well and his health was improving."]
```

If you get en error as you mentioned here:

```
error: cannot convert value of type '(Any) -> Int' to expected argument type '(UnboundedRange_) -> ()'
```

Than you put the word 'index' instead of and index number. Index number is an int, like in array. If you have 3 elements in the list, then the first element from the list has index = 0. The next one is 1, and 2... and so on. Check this link: [swift arrays](https://www.weheartswift.com/arrays/)